# apply a modification on a Button for each ListViewItem in a universal app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have 2 ListviewItems,each one has a btnStar button,one of those Buttons works only,per example when I click on btnStar of ListViewItem1 it modifies btnStar of ListViewItem2's Background,I can't modify the Background color of btnStar of ListViewItem1 when I click on it

this is my xaml:

```
 <ListView  x:Name="listme">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate >
   <DataTemplate >
     <Grid>
       ...
      <Button Background="{Binding ButtonColor}"  x:Name="btnStar" 
Click="btnStar_Click"/>
     </Grid>
   </DataTemplate >
 </ListView.ItemTemplate >
</ListView >
```

and this is the method that I have use when I click on the btnStar Button :

```
bool btnclicked = false; 
private void btnStar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (btnclicked)
            {
                btnStar.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);              
                btnclicked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                btnStar.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);//Gray
                btnclicked = true;
            }
```

this is how I get the ListViewItems:

```
 ObservableCollection<Item> Locals = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
public async void getListePerSearch()
    {
        try
        {
            UriString2 = "URL";
            var http = new HttpClient();
            http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            var response = await http.GetStringAsync(UriString2);
            var rootObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NvBarberry.Models.RootObject>(response);

           foreach (var item in rootObject1.locals)
                {
                    Item listItem = new Item();
                    if (item.fav == 1)
                        {
                         listItem.ButtonColor= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow); //Yellow
                        }

                        else
                        {
                        listItem.ButtonColor= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);//Gray
                        }
                        Locals.Add(listItem);
                }

                listme.ItemsSource = Locals;
   }
```

Item.cs:

```
 public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private SolidColorBrush buttonColor;
        public SolidColorBrush ButtonColor
        {
            get { return buttonColor; }
            set
            {
                buttonColor = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonColor");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
}
```

How can I check if the Button of the selected ListViewItem is clicked,should I use foreach in this method ??

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

Change:

```
  <Button Background="{Binding ButtonColor}"  x:Name="btnStar" Click="btnStar_Click"/>
```

To:

```
  <Button Background="{Binding ButtonColor}"  x:Name="btnStar" Tag="{Binding}" Click="btnStar_Click"/>
```

Change:

```
private void btnStar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (btnclicked)
        {
            btnStar.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);              
            btnclicked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            btnStar.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);//Gray
            btnclicked = true;
        }
```

To:

```
private void btnStar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    var item = btn.Tag as Item;
    item.ButtonColor = item.ButtonColor == Brushes.Gray ? Brushes.Yellow : Brushes.Gray;
}
```

Change all these line:

```
listItem.ButtonColor= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow); 
listItem.ButtonColor= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);//Gray
```

To:

```
listItem.ButtonColor= Brushes.Yellow; 
listItem.ButtonColor= Brushes.Gray;//Gray
```

and change

```
private SolidColorBrush buttonColor;
public SolidColorBrush ButtonColor
{
    get { return buttonColor; }
    set
    {
        buttonColor = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonColor");
    }
}
```

to this:

```
private Brush buttonColor;
public Brush ButtonColor
{
    get { return buttonColor; }
    set
    {
        buttonColor = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonColor");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Sakura for your reply but this doesn't work :(

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,in fact I get this exception { "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} at this line => if (selectedItem.ButtonColor == Brushes.Yellow)

Comment: Did it work? I don't want my answer being acepted if user just feeling that I put lot of work on the question, but actually the answer don't make any help.

Comment: yes Sir it doesn't work,I am trying to solve the problem based on your solution :)

Comment: Do any code I write above cause app throw an error?

Comment: thanks Sir your code works very well,it was my error :D

Comment: Right then. I happy to know my answer solve your problem.